# Neglecting a small part of a square root and then simplifying

Tags: taylor-expansion, rational-functions

I'm trying to verify the following algebraic step from an old textbook, but I'm having trouble getting the same result.

The starting point is here:

\begin{equation}
1 = \frac{\rho_{si}a}{2\epsilon_0} \ln \frac{\frac{\Delta l_i}{2} + \sqrt{a^2 + \left( \frac{\Delta l_i}{2} \right )^2}}{-\frac{\Delta l_i}{2} + \sqrt{a^2 + \left( \frac{\Delta l_i}{2} \right )^2}}
\end{equation}

Here I'm supposed to assume $a << \Delta l_i$. I see two ways to do this immediately:

(1) in the numerator, assume that $\sqrt{a^2 + \left( \frac{\Delta l_i}{2} \right )^2} \approx \sqrt{\left(\frac{\Delta l_i}{2} \right )^2}$

(2) in the denominator, perform a Taylor series expansion of $\sqrt{a^2 + \left( \frac{\Delta l_i}{2} \right )^2}$ and throw out the higher order terms to taste.

Doing this, I get

\begin{equation}
1 = \frac{\rho_{si}a}{2\epsilon_0} \ln \frac{\Delta l_i}{-\frac{\Delta l_i}{2} + \frac{\Delta l_i}{2} + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \left(\frac{a^2}{\frac{\Delta l_i}{2}}\right)}
\end{equation}

which simplifies to

\begin{equation}
1 = \frac{\rho_{si}}{2\epsilon_0} \ln \frac{\Delta l_i^2}{a}
\end{equation}

However, the book has

\begin{equation}
1 = \frac{\rho_{si}a}{\epsilon_0} \ln \frac{\Delta l_i}{a}
\end{equation}

in other words, I've come up with one too many $\Delta l_i$ in the numerator. I've checked the Taylor expansion twice now, and also verified that the rest of the chapter uses $\Delta l_i$, not $\Delta l_i^2$ in subsequent steps.

What am I missing? (The book isn't clear on how the simplification was carried out, only that $a$ should be neglected versus $\Delta l_i$.)

Comment: Actually it seems you are missing a factor of 2. In your computation, you had $a^2$ in the denominator, how did that become just $a$? And then, after you fix that, you have $\ln\dfrac{\Delta l_i^2}{a^2} = 2\ln\dfrac{\Delta l_i}{a}$.

Comment: @mathguy Aha! I see that I was greedy and ignored the log operator. I fixed the typo so my mistake is clearer. If you put that as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: No need, it's good enough as a comment :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mathguy refuses to take credit, but they're the one who spotted it.

The simplification I performed erroneously tries to factor an $a^2$ term from outside the log operator. The expression I should have gotten was

\begin{equation}
1 = \frac{\rho_{si}a}{2\epsilon_0} \ln \frac{\Delta l_i^2}{a^2}
\end{equation}

which you can extract the power from and move outside the log:

\begin{equation}
1 = \frac{\rho_{si}a}{2\epsilon_0} \ln \left(\frac{\Delta l_i}{a}\right)^2 = \frac{\rho_{si}a}{\epsilon_0} \ln \frac{\Delta l_i}{a}
\end{equation}

This lines up with the book's derivation.